# Can't install apps using debians

Tags: deb

I have a problem with installing apps from a debian. I open a .deb file in Ubuntu Software and click the "Install" button. for a few seconds it seems to work, with the meter on the install button appearing and rising normally for a split second. then the meter suddenly disappears and the Install button becomes live again and nothing seems to have happened. I click it in rapid sucession, and this app called "waiting to install" appears and it does absolutely nothing after that. So, how do I install a Debian properly!?
error:
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

do not know how to install app in state unknown

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, downloaded .deb packages fail to be installed because they have unmet dependencies (those are automatically handled when you install software from the repository). Try installing your package manually using the terminal (take a look at this post: [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line/40781#40781)), because you will be able to debug with it.